# Passing variable value as a condition in if statement with React.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm a student and I'm trying to make a summary of a cart for an e-commerce site with React.js for a homework assignment.
I need to set a shipping cost (there are two options for the shipping cost: the first is *free*, the second is *$20*) based on the selected radio button, but I'm not able to do it. I think that the right way can be done with an if statement, but I'm not sure. Can someone guide me on how to achieve this?

This is the code of the page where the buttons are present:

```
        import React, {Component} from 'react';
        import {Col, Row, Button, Form, Card} from 'react-bootstrap';
        import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
        import '../styles/shopping.css';
        import Header from '../components/header';
        import Foot from "../components/foot";
        import Summary from '../components/summary';

        class Shipping extends Component{    
            constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = {
                    activeIndex: ''
                };        
                this.radioButtons = [            
                    {text: 'Free Shipping \n\r Between 2 - 5 working days'},
                    {text: 'Next Day Delivery - $20 \n\r 24 hours from checkout'} 
                    ]
                }      
                updateRadioGroup(i) {
                  this.setState({activeIndex: i})
                }        
            render(){
                let { activeIndex } = this.state;     
                return(
                                <Row>
                                    <Col xs={6} id="ship-sx">
                                    {
                                    this.radioButtons.map((element,i ) => (
                                        <Card className="btn-shipping" class="boxClickCss" key={i} className={activeIndex === i ? 'btn-shipping actv' : 'btn-shipping'}>
                                            <Row>
                                                <Col xs={2} className="center-radio">
                                                    <label className="container-btn-radio">
                                                        <input required type="radio" name="ship" onClick={() => this.updateRadioGroup(i)}/>
                                                        <span className="checkradio"/>
                                                    </label>
                                                </Col>                                        
                                                <Col xs={10}>
                                                    <div style={{maxWidth:"55%"}}>{element.text}</div>
                                                </Col>
                                            </Row>
                                        </Card>
                                    ))
                                    }
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col xs={12} md={4}>
                                        <Summary/>
                                    </Col>
                                </Row>

            )
        }
    }
    export default Shipping;
```

And this is the component included in the page where the shipping price must be visualized:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Col, Row, Accordion, Dropdown, Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
import Coupon from "./coupon";
import SummaryProd from "./summaryProd";
import '../styles/summary.css';

function somma() {
    var z = (localStorage.getItem('price') +20 +20);
    return z;
}
var risultato = somma();

export const  showProduct=()=>{        
    localStorage.getItem('name');
    localStorage.getItem('price');
    localStorage.getItem('description');
    localStorage.getItem('img');
}
export const Summary = () => (             
    (localStorage.getItem('id') !== null) ? ( 
        <>
        <Row>
            <Col id="summary-col">
                <div>
                    <h3>Summary</h3>
                        <hr className='row-shopping'/>
                    </div>                                 
                    <SummaryProd/>
                    <Coupon/>
                    <hr className='row-shopping'/>
                    <div>
                    <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
                        <Accordion.Toggle id="btn-voucher" as={Button} variant="link" eventKey="1" split>
                            <span>HAVE A VOUCHER?</span><Dropdown.Toggle id="voucher-arrow"/>
                        </Accordion.Toggle>                        
                        <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="1">
                        <input/>
                        </Accordion.Collapse>
                    </Accordion>
                    </div>
                    <hr className='row-shopping'/>
                    <div className="summary-details">
                        <span>
                            SUBTOTAL
                        </span>
                        <span>
                            ${localStorage.getItem('price')}
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="summary-details">
                        <span>
                            SHIPPING
                        </span>
                        <span>
                            {/* SHIPPiNG COST */}
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="summary-details">
                        <span>
                            TAXES
                        </span>
                        <span>
                            $20
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <hr className='row-shopping'/>
                    <div className="summary-details">
                        <span>
                            TOTAL
                        </span>

                        <span>

                        </span>
                    </div>
                </Col>
            </Row>
            </>
        ):(
        <Row style={{height: '50vh'}}>
            <Col id="summary-col">
                <div >
                    <h3>Summary</h3>
                    <hr className='row-shopping'/>
                    <span>Your cart is empty!</span>
                </div>
            </Col>
        </Row>           
    )               
)

export default Summary;
```

Comment: What is the shipping cost? How you want to calculate shipping cost? Is it static value?

Comment: @ravibagul91 yes, there are two options for the shipping cost:
the first is **free**, the second is **$20**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        activeIndex: '',
        shippingCost: '',
    };  
    //set cost here only      
    this.radioButtons = [            
        {text: 'Free Shipping \n\r Between 2 - 5 working days', cost: 'Free'},
        {text: 'Next Day Delivery - $20 \n\r 24 hours from checkout', cost: '$20'} 
    ]
}      
updateRadioGroup(i) {
    let shippingCost = this.radioButtons[i].cost;
    this.setState({activeIndex: i, shippingCost }) //set shippingCost in state
}
```

After setting shipping cost you need to pass this to `Summary` component,

```
<Summary shippingCost={this.state.shippingCost} />
```

Usage in `Summary` component,

```
export const Summary = (props) => (   //your props passed 
 ...
 <div className="summary-details">
    <span>
       SHIPPING
    </span>
    <span>
       {props.shippingCost}
    </span>
</div>
...
)
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-6xpgz?fontsize=14) with reduced code.